# Primer for mathematical models of epidemics

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, applications

In a comment to my recent [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354082/relevant-mathematics-to-the-recent-coronavirus-outbreak) Robert Israel wrote: "Mathematical models of epidemics are well-established. Of course we'd like to know the parameters (and to what extent something can be done about them)."

I would be very thankful for explanation of the basic standard mathematical models of epidemics and what are the crucial parameters. Of course, references and link could be useful, but an answer with the actual descriptions of the models will be most helpful.

Comment: There are many excellent references on the subject, but I am not sure if that is what you are looking for. For example, here are some, but there are also some excellent books on these topics; https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1755436517301342, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5726591/, http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/marym/populations/hethcote.pdf, https://www.mcgill.ca/tb/files/tb/lect_1_introduction_modeling.pdf, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2468042716300367

Comment: Books: http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~ahoyerle/math333/ThreeBasicModels.pdf, Mathematical Models in Epidemiology (Texts in Applied Mathematics) Hardcover – October 11, 2019 by Fred Brauer (Author), Carlos Castillo-Chavez (Author), Zhilan Feng (Author), An Introduction to Mathematical Epidemiology (Texts in Applied Mathematics) 1st ed. 2015 Edition by Maia Martcheva  (Author), An Introduction to Mathematical Modeling of Infectious Diseases (Mathematics of Planet Earth) 1st ed. 2018 Edition by Michael Y. Li (Author)

Comment: Handbook of Infectious Disease Data Analysis (Chapman & Hall/CRC Handbooks of Modern Statistical Methods) 1st Edition by Leonhard Held (Editor), Niel Hens (Editor), Philip D O'Neill (Editor), Jacco Wallinga (Editor)

Comment: Dear @Moo, many thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article *Lambert W function* has a section **Epidemiology** (see also the reference [27] in this article, that I don't know). I tried to search related articles and I've found *Application of the Lambert W Function to the SIR Epidemic Model* by Frank Wang (I can to read in the web of the Mathematical Association of America) that the article is from the College Mathematics Journal (March, 2010). I add this comment since (I'm not a professional mathematician) the Lambert $W$ function has many applications, and the article maybe can be interesting for you, isn't required a response.